# Не работают шрифты HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Шрифты привязаны к отдельному CSS, не могу понять почему они не работают

**HTML**

```
<div class="test"><p>test</p></div>
```

**FONT CSS**

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Progress-BoldItalic';
src: url('fonts/Progress-BoldItalic.eot');
src: url('fonts/Progress-BoldItalic.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Progress-BoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Progress-BoldItalic.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

**CSS**

```
.test {
font-family: Progress-BoldItalic;}
```

Comment: Попробуй почитать про подключение шрифтов, скорее всего проблема в этом.
Возможно эта статья поможет (это первая ссылка в гугле, так что не обещаю):
https://moguta.ru/blog/delaem-internet-magazin-vmeste/kak-podklyuchit-shrift-na-sajt-v-css

Comment: в какой папке расположен css? если стили расположены в папке css (как пример), необходимо путь к шрифту задать так url('../fonts/Progress-BoldItalic.eot'); (для остальных форматов шрифта, также необходимо изменить путь)

Answer (score 0):

У вас в самом HTML в теге `<head>` есть тег `<link>`? `<link>` подключает CSS файл к HTML чтобы он роботал.
Виглядит таким образом:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Тег LINK</title>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css">
   <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" 
     title="Статьи с сайта htmlbook.ru" href="http://htmlbook.ru/rss.xml"> 
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://htmlbook.ru/favicon.ico">
  </head> 
  <body>
    <p>...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```